# Headers and line counting in reledmac/reledpar

Tags: sectioning, line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I am converting an old FrameMaker file to XeLaTeX. As it deals with text editions of ancient documents, multiple readings, and the like, it seems to make sense to use `reledmac/reledpar`. However, being new at this, I am not sure I am going about it in the best possible fashion.

Please consider the following MWE below showcasing an original text in Sumerian and Akkadian with a translation into English. I've run into a few issues.

1. The headers "Obverse...", "Reverse", etc. only need to be given once; I do not need separate headers for left and right columns.
2. They can be quite long, i.e. longer than the width of the left column. Thus I found the use of `\pstart[\subsubsection{Obverse...}]` problematic.
3. So I tried to use regular `memoir` header commands outside the edition with column pairs in between. This looked nice but I was not able to figure out how to continue the numbering of each column after a header, as seen in the output from this MWE.
4. Thus I resorted to simulating the headers as single-column text, suppressing the line counting mechanism. This worked quite well as you can see.
5. In some instances, however, I do wish to restart the numbering after a simulated header. This is quite easy by getting rid of the `\pausenumbering` and `\resumenumbering` in favour of `\beginnumbering` and `\endnumbering`. Unfortunately, as a side-effect, the right-hand column is then not numbered continuously, which it always should be regardless.

So the first two questions are: is this the right way to handle my needs, and is it possible to keep continuous numbering in the right column, regardless of whether the left column restarts?

The other thing to note is that the practice in my field is to number each line of text as it appears on the original document. The romanized equivalents, however, can typeset in multiple lines (see the first line of the obverse). In order to avoid numbering part lines, I have entered manual `\skipnumbering` commands as necessary, but this strikes me as potentially error prone if, say, the document font size changes and the line breaks therefore change.

I am wondering whether this is indeed the thing to do.

I have considered the various examples provided in the documentation but given my needs I'm a bit stumped and any pointers would be appreciated.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
 \documentclass[%
    a4paper,            % minus margins = A5
    11pt,               % reduce to 10 if required
    twoside,            % two-sided printing
    one column,         % single column of text on a page
    openright,          % chapters/lessons begin on odd pages only; review later
    ]{memoir}

% GENERAL PAGE LAYOUT (in the order suggested by memoir)
\setulmarginsandblock{67mm}{60mm}{*}    % #1 is upper, #2 is lower, #3 is ratio
\setlrmarginsandblock{50mm}{50mm}{*}    % #1 is spine, #2 is edge, #3 is ratio
%\setheadfoot{⟨headheight⟩}{⟨footskip⟩}
\setheaderspaces{*}{10mm}{*}            % #1 is the head drop, #2 is the head separation, #3 is ratio
%\setmarginnotes{<separation>}{<width>}{<push>}
\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm}               % default is pt
\checkandfixthelayout
%\raggedbottom                          % turn this option on *if* there are too many problems

\nouppercaseheads

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
    \setotherlanguage[]{french}
    \setotherlanguage[spelling=old]{german}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[nosyncpstarts]{reledpar} 
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
    \firstlinenum{1}
    \linenumincrement{1}
    \setlength{\linenumsep}{0.5em}
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
\newcommand{\aw}{Aw~} 
\newcommand{\akk}[1]{{\sffamily\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\smn}[1]{{\sffamily\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0}#1}}
\newcommand{\D}{{\sffamily\textsuperscript{d}}}
\newcommand{\dtm}[1]{{\sffamily\textsuperscript{#1}}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Text Editions}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\large\bfseries\centering}
\counterwithout{subsection}{section}
\newcommand{\presection}{}
\newcommand{\presubsection}{\aw}
\newcommand{\presubsubsection}{}
\setsecnumformat{\csname pre#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsubsectionpresnum}{\textsc{aw}~}}

\subsection{OBJECT}
Here is a multiline description of the object. Here is a multiline description of the object. Here is a multiline description of the object. Here is a multiline description of the object. 

% Simulated subsubsection header "Obverse"
\vskip 3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex
\beginnumbering
\sffamily\large\bfseries\raggedright\pstart\noindent\skipnumbering Obverse (numbered as in YOS~5)\pend
\endnumbering
\vskip 1.5ex plus .2ex
% Obverse in two columns
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent\smn{[gud]-giš} \smn{[gud]-giš} \smn{[gud]-giš} \skipnumbering\smn{[gud]-giš} \smn{[gud]-giš} \par
\noindent\smn{a-ru-a} \akk{nu-úr}–\D\smn{utu}
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\smn{1 gu₄ mu 3(1)}\par
\noindent\akk{a-bu--wa-qar}
\pend
\pstart
\skipnumbering‹space›
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\smn{ì-dab₅} \akk{i-ba-aš-ši}--\smn{dingir}
\pend
\pausenumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{1–2~}(re:) 1 draught ox, votive offering of Nūr–Šamaš (and)
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{3--4~}1 three-year old ox, (votive offering of) Abu--waqar
\pend
\pstart
\skipnumbering
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{5~}Ibašši–{dingir} has taken (them).
\pend
\pausenumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
% Simulated subsubsection header "Obverse"
\vskip 3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex
\resumenumbering
\sffamily\large\bfseries\raggedright\pstart\noindent\skipnumbering Reverse\pend
\pausenumbering
\vskip 1.5ex plus .2ex
% Obverse in two columns
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside} 
\resumenumbering
\pstart
\noindent\smn{[gud]-giš}\par
\noindent\smn{a-ru-a} \akk{nu-úr}–\D\smn{utu}
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\smn{1 gu₄ mu 3(1)}\par
\noindent\akk{a-bu--wa-qar}
\pend
\pstart
\skipnumbering‹space›
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\smn{ì-dab₅} \akk{i-ba-aš-ši}--\smn{dingir}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
\resumenumbering
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{1–2~}(re:) 1 draught ox, votive offering of Nūr–Šamaš (and)
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{3--4~}1 three-year old ox, (votive offering of) Abu--waqar
\pend
\pstart
\skipnumbering
\pend
\pstart
\noindent\textsubscript{5~}Ibašši–{dingir} has taken (them).
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hum, it is not so clear for me. Do you need your number be counted on line numbering? if not, you could forget the \resumenumbering…\pausenumbering and on so one around. If you need them to be in line numbering, you should use the \eledsection mechanism.

Comment: For your question of older line number (as in your original document), you must know that reledmac is (normally) adapted to get correct line number if you change line break by changing font. You must just use a new `latexmk` run (I encourage you to use latemk when using reledmac/reledpar, and in general with LaTeX. It will ensure you to get the correct number of LaTeX runs, and so, to get correct line number).

Comment: Note that actually, I develop a new feature of reledmac which should allow you to transcibe original line number, and to get them in critical footnote.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking  in either of your two comments. Would it help to discuss it in French? We can discuss by email and then post appropriate responses here. I am sending you my email address through your website contact since I can offer separate examples showing the issues that way. (I use XeLaTeXmk btw so that is not an issue.)

Comment: I think I would prefer in French, yes, your problem is complex

Comment: On its way! C'est en route!